# Update Progress is not working inside Html Table in Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, html-table, updatepanel, updateprogress

Here is my code my update progress is not wokring inside Html Table.

Means My requirement is on button click preloader should be visible stating that please wait.

But here my update progress is visible witouht button click 
what should be the issue 
am i doing something wrong.
I have tried lots of different thing.

I have read lots of articles regarding this many people have told that update panel is not compatible with table is that right?

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <table style="width: 920px;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
              <td style="width: 200px;" valign="top">
                <div class="admin_txt">
                    Skin Condition Type :
                </div>
              </td>             
           </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 200px;" valign="top">
            <div class="admin_txt">
                Intro Text :
            </div>
        </td>       
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 200px;" valign="top">
            <div class="admin_txt">
                Reason :
            </div>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 700px;">
            <div class="editor_posi">
                <cc1:Editor ID="editor_reason" Width="650px" Height="200px" runat="server" />
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 200px;" valign="top">
            <div class="admin_txt">
                Treatment :
            </div>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 700px;">
            <div class="editor_posi">
                <cc1:Editor ID="editor_treatment" Width="650px" Height="200px" runat="server" />
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <%--<tr>
    <td style="width: 200px;" valign = "top">
      <div class ="admin_txt">
        FAQs :
      </div>
    </td>
    <td style="width: 700px;">
       <div class = "editor_posi">
          <cc1:Editor ID="editor_faq" Width="650px" Height="200px" runat="server"/>
       </div>
    </td>
    </tr>--%>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 200px;" valign="top">
            <div class="admin_txt">
                Treatment Recommendation:
            </div>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 700px;">
            <div class="editor_posi admin_txt_recm">
                <asp:CheckBoxList ID="treatment_cbl" runat="server">
                </asp:CheckBoxList>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
        <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
            <ProgressTemplate>
                <div>
                    <td style="width: 200px;" valign="top">
                        <div class="admin_txt">
                            &nbsp;
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 700px;">
                        <div class="editor_posi">

                            <div class="img_cls">
                                <img src="images/spinner-mini.gif" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="msg_cls">
                                Please Wait...
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </div>
            </ProgressTemplate>
        </asp:UpdateProgress>
    </tr>

    <asp:Panel ID="msg_pnl" runat="server">
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 200px;" valign="top">
                <div class="admin_txt">
                    &nbsp;
                </div>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 700px;">
                <div class="editor_posi">

                    <div class="img_cls">
                        <img src="images/check.png" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="msg_cls">
                        Your Record Has Been Submitted Successfully.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </asp:Panel>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 200px;" valign="top"></td>
        <td style="width: 700px;">
            <div class="editor_posi">
                <span class="cmd_posi">
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="submit_btn" ImageUrl="~/images/button/submit_btn.jpg"
                        runat="server" OnClick="submit_btn_Click" />
                </span>
                <span class="cmd_posi">
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="reset_btn" ImageUrl="~/images/button/reset_btn.jpg"
                        runat="server" OnClick="reset_btn_Click" />
                </span>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

  </ContentTemplate>                                                                    
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: post your full update panel panel code.

Comment: @Raghubar I have pasted it please check the code

Comment: @Raghubar If i have removed tr & td tag then it is working but it is applying above the table

Comment: Its not table problem. I found only two issue. 1. You have missed td tag just above update progress bar 2. You not mention trigger panel.

Comment: I have put td tag in update progress but please wait is still visisble. what may be the issue